# Python: threading

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to start thread multiple times, but only when it is not running.
There is a simple model what I am trying:

```
import threading 
import time


def up (x, r):
    time.sleep(3)
    r['h'] = x + 1


hum = {'h' : 0}

while True:
    print(hum['h'])
    H = threading.Thread(target = up, args=(hum['h'],hum))
    H.daemon=True
    if not H.isAlive():
        H.start()
    print(threading.active_count())
```

Also what i don't understand is that:
When I run program it prints: 0. Then after 3 seconds it prints:1 and so on after every 3 second it is increased by 1.
But I thought it would print: 0. Then after 3 second it would print: 1. And then immediately increasing fast.
Because after starting first thread it would immediately start the next one and so on. why does this happen?
How not to start a thread 'up', if it's already running?

Comment: Don't you get `RuntimeError: can't start new thread`?

Comment: I tried running your code and I do not get what you explain...instead I get a rapidly increasing number of threads, because you're creating every time a different instance. Could you explain what you see and what you expect a bit better?

Comment: And if you move the definition of the Thread instance out of the while loop you get a `RuntimeError: can't start new thread` as @GyuHyeon Choi suggested.

Comment: @toti08 I am running code in spyder and also get rapidly increasing thread instances but 'hum' is increasing slowly and I don't know why?

Comment: @toti08 here I can move thread definition out of while loop.But if there is situation were args are changing inside while loop then defining it out of while loop is meaningless

Comment: @NikaTvildiani You can't move the thread definition out of the loop, a thread can only be started once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I got your question completely, but here are some thoughts.
When I run your code I get an increasing number of active threads, as you are creating a new thread every time, checking its status (which will always be `not alive`) and then starting it.
What you want to do instead is to check the status of the last run thread and if that's not alive start a new one. In order to do that you should create a new thread if the old one is done:

```
def up (x, r):
    time.sleep(3)
    r['h'] = x + 1


def main():
    hum = {'h' : 0}
    H = threading.Thread(target = up, args=(hum['h'],hum))
    H.daemon=True

    while True:
        # print(hum['h'])
        if not H.isAlive():
            H = threading.Thread(target = up, args=(hum['h'],hum))
            H.daemon=True
            H.start()
            print(threading.active_count())
```

Comment: it is what I want

Comment: But i still don't understand when there is huge number of running threads, why they are not increasing h simultaneously. like when one thread started then on next iteration second thread started immediately.Then   after 3 second first thread increased h by one, but at that  second thread also has finished sleeping and increased h by one. I don't know how to explain what I am trying to say.

Comment: That's because when you start a thread you pass it the value of `hum` in that moment, and `hum['h']` will only be increased 3 seconds after the first thread is started. If meanwhile you start other threads they will receive `0` as `x` parameter, so they'll replace `hum[h]` with 1 (x+1). This is not the ideal situation and it's something you might want to avoid, as it is difficult to control.

Comment: Now I understand. it is situation when i must use lock.

Answer (score 0):

What happens in your code:

- Print the value of `hum['h']`
- Create a thread (note you *create* it, you are not starting it yet)
- Set the value of a property
- If the thread is not started then start it
- Print the count of active threads (*active*, NOT *started*)

Since you replace the `H` variable every time, you'll have a new thread every time that gets immediately started.

If you add a print that says "starting" in the if for the is alive, you'll see that it gets called every time.

Comment: Yes I tried that and understand what happening but how make things working properly. How check if old thread (not replaced) is alive or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) to wait for the thread to finish:

```
import threading 
import time


def up (x, r):
    time.sleep(3)
    r['h'] = x + 1


hum = {'h' : 0}

while True:
    print(hum['h'])
    H = threading.Thread(target = up, args=(hum['h'],hum))
    H.daemon=True
    H.start()
    H.join()
    print(threading.active_count())
```

If you don't want to wait, you can just save the current running thread in a variable and check it in the loop:

```
import threading 
import time


def up (x, r):
    time.sleep(3)
    r['h'] = x + 1


hum = {'h' : 0}

current_thread = None

while True:
    print(hum['h'])
    if current_thread is None:
        current_thread = threading.Thread(target = up, args=(hum['h'],hum))
        current_thread.daemon=True
        current_thread.start()
    elif not current_thread.isAlive():
        current_thread = threading.Thread(target = up, args=(hum['h'],hum))
        current_thread.daemon=True
        current_thread.start()
```

Comment: I don't want to wait.I want constantly printing while h is changing.